# Loop through 2-dim matrix diagonally, but the other way

Tags: c, loops, diagonal

I'm having trouble looping through an NxM matrix the other way.

This probably isn't everything I could have tried but I already tried finding this on google, and using all kind of different border-values, also tried substracting one index of the other over and over, but I can't seem to get a hang of it. The last thing I did, was create a copy of the matrix, and swap the rows through by for loop until last was first and first was last. this works, but is not what I want.

The Loop down there starts at the top Left of the matrix and works through from bottom left to top right. I want anotherone to start at the bottom left and work through from bottom right to top left, or from top left to bottom right.

Loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i + 1 < ROWCOUNT + COLCOUNT; i++) {
    printf("\n");
    for(int j = 0; j - 1 < i; j++) {
        int n = i - j;
        int m = j;
        if(n < ROWCOUNT && m < COLCOUNT) {
            printf("  %d %d  ", n, m);
        }
    }
}
Output:
  0 0
  1 0    0 1
  2 0    1 1    0 2
  3 0    2 1    1 2    0 3
  4 0    3 1    2 2    1 3    0 4
  5 0    4 1    3 2    2 3    1 4    0 5
  5 1    4 2    3 3    2 4    1 5
  5 2    4 3    3 4    2 5
  5 3    4 4    3 5
  5 4    4 5
  5 5
```

EDIT: I will try to show you what I'm trying to do.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
G   H   I   J   K   L
M   N   O   P   Q   R
S   T   U   V   W   X
Y   Z   AA  AB  AC  AD
AE  AF  AG  AH  AI  AJ
```

My loop goes through this 6x6 matrix the following way:

```
A
G  B
M  H  C
S  N  I  D
Y  T  O  J  E
AE Z  U  P  K  F
AF AA V  Q  L
AG AB W  R
AH AC X
AI AD
AJ
```

I am searching for a loop to go trough the other way. Basically somehow like this:

```
AE
AF Y
AG Z  S
AH AA T  M
AI AB U  N  G
AJ AC V  O  H  A
AD W  P  I  B
R  K  D
L  E
F
```

EDIT: @pmg provided me with a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot. In this Example I set
#define ROWCOUNT 6
#define COLCOUNT 6

Comment: I have not understood from the description how you want to output the matrix. The question should start with the description of what you are trying to do. And only after that what you have done or investigated.

Comment: [challenge accepted](https://ideone.com/B0fjEl)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry, I hope it is better to understand now!

Comment: @pmg Oh my god! You did it! I didn't recognize that is a link. Thank you so much!

Comment: That link isn't exactly what you wanted after the edit, just tweak it: it should be fairly easy :)

Comment: @pmg Thank you so much! No need to even tweak it, this is perfectly fine, I just needed to loop diagonally left. The output is upsite down compared to my example, this does'nt matter at all! It's basically the same. Love you dude! I don't even know how long I've alredy been trying to accomplish just that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you are looking for, but just loop on the other way:

```
#include  "stdio.h"
#define ROWCOUNT  6
#define COLCOUNT 6

int main(void) {
    for(int i = ROWCOUNT - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLCOUNT; j++) {
            printf("  %d %d  ", i, j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

output

```
5 0    5 1    5 2    5 3    5 4    5 5  
4 0    4 1    4 2    4 3    4 4    4 5  
3 0    3 1    3 2    3 3    3 4    3 5  
2 0    2 1    2 2    2 3    2 4    2 5  
1 0    1 1    1 2    1 3    1 4    1 5  
0 0    0 1    0 2    0 3    0 4    0 5
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, but this is vertically, starting at bottom right going left row by row!

I'm looking for the output to look something like this:
5 0  --  
5 1  -  4 0  --  
5 2  -  4 1 -  3 0  --
....

EDIT: Why can't I format my text in these comments down here?

Comment: @Carlos update to match your output, for next question think to put expected output it can help.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I hope this edit will explain what I am trying to do...

Comment: @Ôrel, I'm afraid you are not proceeding diagonally, but by columns/rows from the bottom up.  The idea is to go diagonally, like bishops in chess.

Answer (score 0):

Both diagonals have the property that every cell indices add to a constant or their difference is constant.  In your case, the indices must add to a constant.  Just consider a cell (the first cell to be printed) that is on the diagonal you want, and then as you add to one index, subtract to the other the same quantity, making the sum the same.  This way you can begin with an add of zero:

```
i = 0; j = 0;
```

then, add one to the sum and follow:

## pru.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int N = 10;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:")) != EOF) {
            switch(opt) {
            case 'n': N = atoi(optarg); break;
            }
    } /* while */

    int sum;
    /* maximum value is (N-1) + (N-1) = 2N-2 */
    for (sum = 0; sum <= 2*N - 2; sum++) {
            /* initial values */
            int i = sum < N ? sum : N-1; /* will be decremented */
            int j = sum - i; /* must add to sum, will be incremented */
            char *sep = "";
            for (; i >= 0 && j < N; i--, j++) {
                    printf("%sA[%d, %d]", sep, i, j);
                    sep = " -> ";
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The example code prints the sequence of indices to print:

```
$ pru -n 5
A[0, 0]
A[1, 0] -> A[0, 1]
A[2, 0] -> A[1, 1] -> A[0, 2]
A[3, 0] -> A[2, 1] -> A[1, 2] -> A[0, 3]
A[4, 0] -> A[3, 1] -> A[2, 2] -> A[1, 3] -> A[0, 4]
A[4, 1] -> A[3, 2] -> A[2, 3] -> A[1, 4]
A[4, 2] -> A[3, 3] -> A[2, 4]
A[4, 3] -> A[3, 4]
A[4, 4]
```

---

In the case of the difference of indices, you have:

## pru2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int N = 10;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:")) != EOF) {
            switch(opt) {
            case 'n': N = atoi(optarg); break;
            }
    } /* while */

    int dif;
    /* difference ranges from -(N-1) to +(N-1) */
    for (dif = -N+1; dif <= N-1; dif++) {
            /* initial values, dif = i - j */
            int i = dif > 0 ?    0 : dif; /* will be incremented */
            int j = dif > 0 ? -dif :   0; /* will be incremented */
            char *sep = "";
            for (; i < N && j < N; i++, j++) {
                    printf("%sA[%d, %d]", sep, i, j);
                    sep = " -> ";
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

that will give:

```
A[4, 0]
A[3, 0] -> A[4, 1]
A[2, 0] -> A[3, 1] -> A[4, 2]
A[1, 0] -> A[2, 1] -> A[3, 2] -> A[4, 3]
A[0, 0] -> A[1, 1] -> A[2, 2] -> A[3, 3] -> A[4, 4]
A[0, 1] -> A[1, 2] -> A[2, 3] -> A[3, 4]
A[0, 2] -> A[1, 3] -> A[2, 4]
A[0, 3] -> A[1, 4]
A[0, 4]
```